# Braintree passing shipping address with Request

Tags: vb.net, braintree, braintree-data

I am new to VB.net while using braintree, it is working fine, now I need to pass shipping details with the payment request. How can I do it

```
If Request.Form("payment_method_nonce") <> "" Then
    Dim strStatus As String = ""    
    Dim gateway As New Braintree.BraintreeGateway    
    With gateway
        .Environment = Braintree.Environment.SANDBOX
        .PublicKey = "*********"
        .PrivateKey = "*************"
        .MerchantId = "*************"
    End With

    Dim transactionRequest As New Braintree.TransactionRequest    
    With transactionRequest
        .Amount = 100
        .PaymentMethodNonce = Request.Form("payment_method_nonce")
    End With

    Dim result As Braintree.Result(Of Braintree.Transaction) = gateway.Transaction.Sale(transactionRequest)
    If result.Errors Is Nothing Then
        If result.Target.Status.ToString = Braintree.TransactionStatus.AUTHORIZED.ToString Then
            strStatus = "Payment is " & result.Target.Status.ToString
            Dim result1 As Braintree.Result(Of Braintree.Transaction) = gateway.Transaction.SubmitForSettlement(result.Target.Id)
            strStatus = strStatus & " And Now its " & result1.Target.Status.ToString
            Label1.Text = "Paid"
        Else
            strStatus = result.Target.Status.ToString
        End If
    Else
        strStatus = result.Message.ToString
        Label1.Text = "Not Paid"
    End If
    status.Text = strStatus
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I'm a developer at Braintree.</sub>

You can add the shipping address as part of the transaction by specifying [ShippingAddress](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/dotnet#shipping) in your `TransactionRequest` object. `ShippingAddress` would be created as an `AddressRequest` object. You can see a full .NET example which includes creating a shipping address [on our developers site](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/dotnet#full-example).

As for how to do this with VB.net, based on your code snippet, you should be able to do something like this:

```
Dim shippingAddressRequest As New Braintree.AddressRequest    
With shippingAddressRequest
    .FirstName = "John"
    .LastName = "Smith"
    .StreetAddress = "123 Example St."
    .Locality = "Chicago"
    .Region = "IL"
    .PostalCode = "60601"
    .CountryCodeAlpha2 = "US"
End With
```

Then modify your `transactionRequest` to be like this:

```
Dim transactionRequest As New Braintree.TransactionRequest   
With transactionRequest
    .Amount = 100
    .PaymentMethodNonce = Request.Form("payment_method_nonce")
    .ShippingAddress = shippingAddressRequest
End With
```

If you need any other assistance related to this, I recommend reaching out to [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com).